# How to hand solder pads underneath an IC?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, soldering, pcb-assembly

I have to design a board with a package case called MSOP-16

It has a large ground pad underneath the IC.  What are good methods for soldering this pad by hand with a soldering iron?

Since it is a prototype, I was thinking to put a large enough via inside of the pad and to heat the via and drop solder through it from the other side after the outer pins have already been soldered.

Comment: Yes, I did not see that question.  Thanks for showing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Sparkfun "[reflow skillet](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/59)" method.